# Reducing orbit decay time for dead satellites

Tags: orbital-motion

Would it be cost effective to inflate a large balloon on a satellite approaching the end of its useful life to increase drag and reduce its time in orbit?

Comment: By the metrics of https://www.gaerospace.com/projects/GOLD/area_time_product.html, the "inflation-maintained ultra-thin envelope" is the best method of drag enhancement. Cost is not part of the calculation, however.

Comment: What will you not put on the satellite to give up space and weight for the balloon device?

Comment: @JonCuster You'll make the satellite bigger, but you'll be allowed to put it in a longer lifetime orbit if you can efficiently deorbit it at its end of life.

Comment: I suspect one of the greatest concerns would be heating the gas within the balloon without damaging the balloon.  As the drag force heats the balloon, the necessarily flexible material gets more and more hot.  The pressure within the balloon increases.  As altitude decreases, air pressure increases, which would decrease the effect of the pressure within the balloon.  I suspect it could work, but it would be difficult to control.